# How to limit line length for email XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt, email

I'm trying to create a report in an email and email daemons chop lines if they're over ~ 2040 characters long.
I'm using XSLT to build the email report and I need to break up these lines but I still need the link to work.

```
<xsl:variable name="encoded_url">
    <xsl:value-of select="saxon:string-to-base64Binary(concat(PROTOCOL,'://',URL),'UTF8')" xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"/>
</xsl:variable>
<dd style="{$style-dd}">
    <a title="View URL"
        href="{$baseHref}report?url={$encoded_url}" style="{$style-links}">
        <xsl:call-template name="break-url" >
            <xsl:with-param name="url" select="URL" />
            <xsl:with-param name="length">75</xsl:with-param>
            <xsl:with-param name="lines">999</xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </a>
```

This isn't my code and I'm not real familiar with XSL but I've searched on here and on the web and I'm not really seeing an awesome solution.

Comment: @Thomas-Schultz: Could you, please, provide a complete (but minimal) example -- the source XML document (as minimal as possible), the complete XSLT stylesheet (as minimal as possible) and the wanted result when the provided XSLT stylesheet is applied on the provided XML document? THe lack of these makes working on your problem more of a guesswork than logical activity. Please.

Comment: Sorry I didn't check back in time to add that in there. Alejandro nailed it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath 2.0 expression:

```
string-join(for $line in tokenize(line,'&#xA;'),
                $length in string-length($line)
            return if ($length > $pMaxLength)
                   then substring(replace($line,
                                          concat('(.{1,',
                                                 $pMaxLength,
                                                 '})'),
                                          '$1&#xA;'),
                                  1,
                                  $length + ceiling($length div $pMaxLength) -1)
                   else $line,
            '&#xA;')
```

For test, this input:

```
<line>
line1
line2 line2 line2 line2
line3line3
line4line4
line5line5line5line5line5
</line>
```

With this XSLT 2.0 stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="pMaxLength" select="10"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of
         select="string-join(
                     for $line in tokenize(line,'&#xA;'),
                         $length in string-length($line)
                     return if ($length > $pMaxLength)
                            then substring(replace($line,
                                                   concat('(.{1,',
                                                          $pMaxLength,
                                                          '})'),
                                                   '$1&#xA;'),
                                           1,
                                           $length +
                                           ceiling($length div $pMaxLength) - 1)
                            else $line,
                     '&#xA;')"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
line1
line2 line
2 line2 li
ne2
line3line3
line4line4
line5line5
line5line5
line5
```

Just in case, this XSLT 1.0 stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="line/text()" name="lines">
        <xsl:param name="pString" select="."/>
        <xsl:param name="pMaxLength" select="10"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($pString,'&#xA;')">
                <xsl:call-template name="lines">
                    <xsl:with-param name="pString" 
                     select="substring-before($pString,'&#xA;')"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="pMaxLength" 
                     select="$pMaxLength"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
                <xsl:call-template name="lines">
                    <xsl:with-param name="pString" 
                     select="substring-after($pString,'&#xA;')"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="pMaxLength" 
                     select="$pMaxLength"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring($pString,1,$pMaxLength),
                                             '&#xA;')"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates 
                 select="current()[string-length($pString) > $pMaxLength]">
                    <xsl:with-param name="pString"
                     select="substring($pString,$pMaxLength+1)"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="pMaxLength" select="$pMaxLength"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @Thomas Schultz: You are wellcome!